# Where to look for damage when steel strings are used on a classical Ibanez?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings, classical-guitar

Ok, so when I was a kid, the guitar my dad taught me my first few chords on, was this Ibanez classical acoustic. I started playing guitar as a kid, and I quit as a kid. So now as an adult (age 30), I decided to REALLY start playing. over a year ago, I took the old nylon strings off, and put steel strings on.

Yesterday, I started reading to NEVER do that. I instantly panicked and removed the strings. I also ordered a new guitar to be picked up at guitar center with metal strings, as well as some nylon ones to put back on this old Ibanez. this cheap, old, starter guitar has ALOT of sentimental value to me.

My question is, having metal strings on this guitar, while playing at least an hour a day, for the past year, what type of damage should I be looking for? Everything I've been reading says it'll sound nice at first, but shortly after the neck will snap. Its been a year now and that hasn't happened.

I am also looking around the seam, where the neck meets the body, and I am not seeing any cracking at all. Anything else I should look for? Sounds great still even with nylon string.

Comment: You've probably been lucky. Play it with nylons and take no notice.

Comment: Long paragraphs in narrow fields are hard to read, most especially in sans serif fonts. Your edit has made it no easier.

Comment: Hi, Joe, and welcome to the forum. Tim has a nice answer for you and I tend to agree with you. if you can upload good, sharp pictures of the bridge, the headstock and the neck (as seen from the side of the guitar) perhaps we can give you further information

Comment: Hi Joe, I've purged non constructive comments and edited the post so it's easy to see how this post can be improved. As mkorman said a picture can help improve the question further along with a few more formatting changes to make sure the important points are correctly emphasized.

Answer (score 5):

More than likely you've been fortunate, and no damage has occurred. The areas where it would manifest itself are around the bridge, where the body itself may be lifting, or the bridge itself is being ripped from the body. The bracing inside the body *may* have been affected or loosened by extra strain.

The neck may be not as straight as it originally was, resuting in the action being somewhat high. It may have twisted due to possible mismatch of tension from the steel strings - check both these by sighting down the neck/fingerboard.

You also check the heel at the back, where neck and body are joined. It's glued at that place, so stress could show there.

There is sometimes a joint at the top of the neck, behind the nut. That could be starting to open up due to extra tension. With none of these symptoms showing, take no notice, and continue enjoying it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you "panicked and removed the strings" there probably isn't damage.  I have seen the kind of damage that this can cause and the two things I'd look for are (1) the bridge peeling away from the guitar top, and (2) the top pulling away from the sides all the way down on the "bottom" of the guitar.  The is where the guitar is weak and will succumb to the stress of the strings.  On a high quality classical the top would be one layer of soft wood.  If left on long enough the top will bulge up behind the bridge and the top will separate from the body directly behind the bridge.  The bulge itself would be a third form of damage to look for.  On a cheaper model the top might actually be plywood and the bracing and joints a little thicker, or tougher.  If any of these have occurred you may be able to get it fixed by a luthier if you really want.  I suspect that if this has not occurred and you just put nylon strings on it it will be fine.

Comment: "Panicked and removed the strings" - after one year of playing it for an hour a day!